# How to open the most recent file in a folder using Terminal (Unix commands)

Tags: unix, terminal, automator

I am trying to implement this as an Automator action.
I would like to open the most recent file added to the Downloads folder.
Is this possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For shell scripts, you can use the **Run Shell Script** action in your Automator workflow.

Most utilities use the modification time, but `ls` can be used to sort by creation date.  Adapted from a couple of StackExchange topics, you can use something like the following (replace the action’s default script):

`open "$(find ~/Downloads -type f -not -path '*/.*' -exec ls -Ut {} + | head -1)"`

The above statement uses `find` to get files (but not dot files) in the user’s **Downloads** folder, passes them on to `ls` to sort by the creation time, and then gets the first one for the `open` command.

If there aren’t any files found, a Finder window will be opened to the user’s home folder.

Comment: The OP refers to _"the most recent file added to the Downloads"_, which—depending on what the OP was thinking when he wrote this—might not be the same as _creation date_.  For instance, I can move a file I created yesterday to the downloads folder, which would become the file most recently added to that folder, but it wouldn't be the file in that folder created most recently.

Comment: @CJK - Agreed, it depends on what "recent" is.  I just went for the latest download.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want a quick way to open the most recent file from the terminal (not Automator)

```
open "$(ls -t ~/Downloads | head -1)"
```